# Regular expression for certain URL

Tags: c#, regex, url

What would be a regular expression for:

https://lenovo:44333

although 44333 is unlikely to change - just want to make sure user types this in w/o Errors...

Comment: Which part is unchanged?

Comment: unchanged is https. Will this work: http://[A-Z][a-z].*:[0-9].*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You could try this*

***`((http|https):\/{2})+([a-zA-Z]+\:[0-9]*)+`***

***http://regexr.com/3fnjt***

> [image]

*Or per @PSGuy*

***`https?:\/{2}[A-Za-z]+\:[0-9]*`***

> [image]

Comment: This also works: `https?:\/{2}[A-Za-z]+\:[0-9]*`. I believe it may be easier for the regex engine to interpret.

Comment: @PSGuy Cool- Thanks